# Create an asset programmatically Azure Media Setrvice v3 PHP

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-media-services

I'm trying to create an asset with the Guzzle client using this code

```
 $response = $this->httpClient->request('PUT', $request_url, [
      'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
      ],
      'form_params' => [],
    ]);
```

I'm getting this error

```
400 Bad Request` response: { "error": { "code": "InvalidResource", "message": "The input resource must be specified in the request bod (truncated...) in GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create() (line 113 of /var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php).
```

I was able to create assets with postman using the same credentials and tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to point to the missing storage account name in the body.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/media/assets/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#create-an-asset

Can you check if body is being sent correctly.

Comment: yes, they are all non-required fields, so you just need to send the properties array in the body... Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I won't delete the question so while searching I found a solution you need to send a body like this in order to create an asset.

```
 $response = $this->httpClient->request('PUT', $request_url, [
      'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
      ],
        'json' => [
            'properties' => [
              'description' => ''
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```